# Rails 7: tailwind.config.js is not picked up or supported out of the box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

In a new Rails 7 project created with the `css tailwind` argument, Tailwind itself works as expected. However, making changes to the `tailwind.config.js` file are not picked up. No explanation is given in the documentation, and it's also difficult to Google as you mostly get answers related to Node/React/JS frameworks.

An [issue was opened that was similar to this back in 2021](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/25), but the solution it contained doesn't seem to work anymore. With all of the changes in architecture from Rails 6.x to Rails 7.x, that's often the case.

Anyone have any experience making this work? This seems like a baseline thing. It's bizarre to me that this isn't hooked up to work in the "Rails way" from project initialization.

Comment: having the same issue, no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you might need to look at

1. Is `const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')` declared in the first lane of your `tailwind.config.js`?

```js
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  // ...
}
```

2. Make sure that the file is in the root directory of your project; I was struggling with the same problem and didn't notice that the file was under `config`